# Is a successful transaction on Paypal Sandbox endpointconfirmation that I have met their upgrade standards

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am ensuring the logic that if I have upgraded my SSl and have successfully completed a transaction in Paypal's sandbox, that this means that I'm good to go as far as their coming upgrades?

It is my understanding that their test sandbox like https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp are setup with the new requirements an will fail if the system does not have the new requirements.So a successful transaction on this test sandbox means we are good to go, Paypal upgrade wise right?

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, an end-to-end payment test against the sandbox API endpoint will ensure your server compatibility.

Or you may simply put a connection test from your host to verify:

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the verification!